# out of memory weblogic - is it recoverable

Tags: out-of-memory

Recently one of our servers threw an out of memory and it seemed to stop
My question is - is an out of memory always non recoverable in an application server ?

Lets say I try and store GB's of data into the http session - will this throw an out of memory error ?

Will this be an unrecoverable error for weblogic such that server will shutdown ?

I am assuming the minute my http session is invalidated ( logout , timeout ) - the gb worth of data will get garbage collected and server should work fine ?

Thanks
satish

Answer (score 0):

An out-of-memory error can be thrown by many instances -- for example, a webserver might emit a warning when it tries to allocate memory for a new session handler, but can't. In that case, it's up to the application seeing the memory allocation fail to handle that gracefully (or not), and thus the program will crash (losing all its unsaved state) or not.

If the operating system (eg. Linux) logs an out-of-memory error, it probably means it had to kill a specific process (eg. the HTTP server), and there almost certainly was a data loss.

Answer (score 0):

Once an Out Of Memory error occurs the WebLogic server will continue to experience problems until it eventually crashes/shuts down - that is unless the condition causing the out of memory error clears up.

Out Of Memory errors detected by a WebLogic server which cause them to 'crash' can be avoided.  This is avoided not in the sense of restoring/keeping any kind of data BUT in safely shutting down and bringing the Managed Server back online automatically when an Out Of Memory error is detected.  I believe you must be using NodeManager to enable this process.

[This Oracle document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13701/overload.htm#CNFGD151) describes this process briefly, while [this post](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_weblogic_overload_protection.htm) may explain it a little better.